# Globally instaling packages doesn't work (node.js, npm)

Tags: node.js, express, npm

For example I installed express with global (-g) parameter. In node.js/node_modules folder express doesn't exists.

I tried to install it without global parameter and it works perfectly.

How to install it globally?

Thanks.

Comment: can't you run `express` from command line.

Comment: To install globally you need to use `sudo` like so `sudo install module_name -g` (if you're on *nix system).

Comment: @Pono, I use windows. I tried to run command line by administrator. But it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Are there any error messages? And where is your node.exe installed (in case the path is just too long)?

Comment: AFAIK -g required for utils like bower and grunt which can be used from comandline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing modules via npm with `-g` is only for modules that provide command-line utilities, *not* for making any ordinary module accessible from anywhere.

So if you are looking to use the command-line `express` project generator utility/command, you need to use `npm install -g express-generator` instead.

If you want to `require('express');` in your application, then you need to install express with `npm install express`.